# What is the tailbone for?

Tags: bones, evolution, tailbone-coccyx

As every "evolution guy" says,  "Our tailbone is a remnant of our evolution"
But a site says, "It helps you about sitting"

Does our tailbone really help us sit?

Comment: A reference to the site making that claim would be helpful.

Comment: It is a remenant and it provides the attachment of muscles and film terminable internally

Comment: Related: https://health.stackexchange.com/q/11037/3120

Comment: @BillOertell https://sorularlaislamiyet.com/insanda-kuyruk-sokumunun-olmasi-evrime-delil-gosteriliyor-kuyruk-sokumunun-bir-islevi-yok-mudur and a science book that explains how evolution is debunked http://fs.fmanager.net/files/book/pdf/en/evolution.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to an online article [See Reference], “The tailbone derived its name because some people believe it is a ‘leftover’ part from human evolution, though the notion that the tailbone serves no purpose is wrong,...”
A look at an anatomy reference book will reveal that many muscles, tendons and ligaments attach to the tailbone (a.k.a. coccyx); these appendages serve to stabilize us when we sit.

An online visual can be found [here](https://www.healthline.com/human-body-maps/coccyx).

And if there is still any lingering doubt about the tailbone helping us sit, sitting is certainly cumbersome when the tailbone is [unhealthy (coccydynia).](https://www.medicinenet.com/coccydynia/article.htm)

---

Reference:

[Human Tailbone: Evidence of Evolution?](http://www.wnd.com/2013/02/human-tailbone-evidence-of-evolution/)